# Unable to send mail using Office 365 SMTP settings in Snipe IT PHP

Tags: php, swiftmailer, laravel-artisan

Facing the following issue while sending email using swift mailer in PHP

```
[2020-06-22 00:38:48] production.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.office365.com:587 (Permission denied) {"userId":1,"email":"xxx@dhdigital.co.in","exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.office365.com:587 (Permission denied) at /var/www/snipeit/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->{closure}(2, 'stream_socket_c...', '/var/www/snipei...', 272, Array)
#1 /var/www/snipeit/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(272): stream_socket_client('tcp://smtp.offi...', 13, 'Permission deni...', 30, 4, Resource id #662)
#2 /var/www/snipeit/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(58): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->establishSocketConnection()
#3 /var/www/snipeit/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(143): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array)
#4 /var/www/snipeit/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(65): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#5 /var/www/snipeit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(451): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#6 /var/www/snipeit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(235): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#7 /var/www/snipeit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php(64): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->send(Object(Illuminate\\Support\\HtmlString), Array, Object(Closure))
...(redacted)
```

The mail settings are correct I cross validated them. The system is hosted on CentOS and firewalld is disabled.

**Update**
SMTP Settings

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=dhprojects@dhdigital.co.in
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDR=dhprojects@dhdigital.co.in
MAIL_FROM_NAME=dhprojects@dhdigital.co.in
MAIL_REPLYTO_ADDR=dhprojects@dhdigital.co.in
MAIL_REPLYTO_NAME=SnipeIT
MAIL_BACKUP_NOTIFICATION_ADDRESS=xxx@dhdigital.co.in
```

Comment: Do you have 2 step verification on your email account ? If yes - delete that and try again.

Comment: Don't have it enabled. I double checked.

Comment: Have you tried using other ports? Eg: 465

Comment: Tried with 465. Same error. I'm updating the question with better error stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized finally that the problem is with selinux setting on my CentOS. SELinux was enforced so it was not letting me establish a connection on that particular port. Things started working once I disabled it.